# Python: Removing a range of numbers from array list

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, range

Im having issues removing elements from a range a through b from an array list. The solutions ive searched online seem to only work for individual elements, adjacent elements and or elements that are whole numbers. Im dealing with float numbers.

```
self.genx = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)

temp_select = self.genx[1:3] #I want to remove numbers from 1 - 3 from genx
print(temp_select)
self.genx = list(set(self.genx)-set(temp_select))
print(self.genx)
plt.plot(self.genx,self.geny)
```

However I get the following in the console and this is because im subtracting floats rather than whole numbers so it literally subtracts rather than removing which is what it would do if dealing with whole numbers:

genx: [ 0.0 ,  0.1 , 0.2 ,  0.3 , 0.4 , 0.5 , 0.6 , 0.7 , 0.8 , 0.9 , 1.0,  1.1 , 1.2 , 1.3 , 1.4 , 1.5 , 1.6 , 1.7 , 1.8 , 1.9 , 2.0, , 2.1 , 2.2 , 2.3 , 2.4 , 2.5 , 2.6 , 2.7 , 2.8 , 2.9
 , 3.0 , 3.1 , 3.2 , 3.3 , 3.4 , 3.5 , 3.6 , 3.7 , 3.8 , 3.9 , 4.0 , 4.1 , 4.2 , 4.3 , 4.4
, 4.5 , 4.6 , 4.7 , 4.8 , 4.9]

temp_select: [ 0.1  0.2]

genx(after subtracted): [0.0, 0.5, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.5, 1.0, 1.1000000000000001, 0.70000000000000007, 0.90000000000000002, 2.7000000000000002, 0.30000000000000004, 2.9000000000000004, 1.9000000000000001, 3.3000000000000003, 0.40000000000000002, 4.7000000000000002, 3.4000000000000004, 2.2000000000000002, 2.8000000000000003, 1.4000000000000001, 0.60000000000000009, 3.6000000000000001, 1.3, 1.2000000000000002, 4.2999999999999998, 4.2000000000000002, 4.9000000000000004, 3.9000000000000004, 3.8000000000000003, 2.3000000000000003, 4.8000000000000007, 3.2000000000000002, 1.7000000000000002, 2.5, 3.5, 1.8, 4.1000000000000005, 2.4000000000000004, 4.4000000000000004, 1.6000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004, 2.6000000000000001, 4.6000000000000005, 2.1000000000000001, 3.1000000000000001, 3.7000000000000002, 4.5]

Comment: Take note that square brackets `[]` are used for *index* based access. `self.genx[1:3]` means "first and second element of `self.genx`". This is totally unrelated to the *value* store at these indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test this but you should be able to do something like the following:

```
self.genx = [ item for item in self.genx if not range_min < item < range_max ]
```

Comment: This worked nicely! However it would round the numbers. So if I set min=2, max =4, genx is: 

[0.0, 0.10000000000000001, 0.20000000000000001, 0.30000000000000004, 0.40000000000000002, 0.5, 0.60000000000000009, 0.70000000000000007, 0.80000000000000004, 0.90000000000000002, 1.0, 1.1000000000000001, 1.2000000000000002, 1.3, 1.4000000000000001, 1.5, 1.6000000000000001, 1.7000000000000002, 1.8, 1.9000000000000001, 2.0, 4.0, 4.1000000000000005, 4.2000000000000002, 4.2999999999999998, 4.4000000000000004, 4.5, 4.6000000000000005, 4.7000000000000002, 4.8000000000000007, 4.9000000000000004]

Fixable?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.genx = [ item for item in self.genx if not range_min <= item <= range_max ]
```

Is this what you want??